# Python-Request - Receiving pointer errors when trying to request data of a website

Tags: python, pointers, python-requests

I'm currently using Python 3.7.6, running the code in a Jupyter Notebook and trying to retrieve data of a website by using the library "request" and I'm receiving a Pointer error -

**Code:**

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

source = requests.get('http://bvmf.bmfbovespa.com.br/indices/ResumoCarteiraTeorica.aspx?Indice=IBOV&idioma=pt-br').text
```

**Error:**

```
OSError: [WinError 10014] - The system detected an invalid pointer address in attempting to use a pointer argument in a call

[...]

NewConnectionError: <urllib3.connection.HTTPConnection object at 0x00000179055507C8>: Failed to establish a new connection: [WinError 10014] The system detected an invalid pointer address in attempting to use a pointer argument in a call

[...]

MaxRetryError: HTTPConnectionPool(host='bvmf.bmfbovespa.com.br.x.ecf9251d0725104833087180eb40dc1a5570.9270ee5e.id.opendns.com', port=80): Max retries exceeded with url: /h/bvmf.bmfbovespa.com.br/indices/ResumoCarteiraTeorica.aspx?X-OpenDNS-Session=_ecf9251d0725104833087180eb40dc1a55709270ee5e_JPweB49M_Indice=IBOV&idioma=pt-br (Caused by NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.HTTPConnection object at 0x00000179055507C8>: Failed to establish a new connection: [WinError 10014] The system detected an invalid pointer address in attempting to use a pointer argument in a call'))

[...]

ConnectionError: HTTPConnectionPool(host='bvmf.bmfbovespa.com.br.x.ecf9251d0725104833087180eb40dc1a5570.9270ee5e.id.opendns.com', port=80): Max retries exceeded with url: /h/bvmf.bmfbovespa.com.br/indices/ResumoCarteiraTeorica.aspx?X-OpenDNS-Session=_ecf9251d0725104833087180eb40dc1a55709270ee5e_JPweB49M_Indice=IBOV&idioma=pt-br (Caused by NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.HTTPConnection object at 0x00000179055507C8>: Failed to establish a new connection: [WinError 10014] The system detected an invalid pointer address in attempting to use a pointer argument in a call'))
```

Note: When I try to run the exact same code on my personal computer it works, however when I try to run at my job's it doesn't.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was actually a proxy issue.
After the following change in the code I could access the content of the website -

```
proxies = {
    "http": "http://myproxy:myport"
}

source = requests.get('http://bvmf.bmfbovespa.com.br/indices/ResumoCarteiraTeorica.aspx?Indice=IBOV&idioma=pt-br', proxies=proxies).text
soup = BeautifulSoup(source, 'html.parser')
```